# Remove (null) git Remote

Tags: git, git-remote

```
$ git remote -v
(null)  git@github.com:username/Savvy.git (fetch)
(null)  git@github.com:username/Savvy.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:username/SavvyCode.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:username/SavvyCode.git (push)
```

How can we delete the *(null)* remote above? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know, how this can happen, but did you ty `git remote rm "(null)"`? :X

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the `.git/config` file (".git" is a subdirectory in your project's directory).  It's an INI-style file which contains a section for each remote, which look like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = <REPOSITORY_URL>
```

So look for strange-looking remotes.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the CLI and remove it by doing this command:

```
git remote rm "(null)"
```